# Magic: the Gathering: Flavor Test

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Below is a list of encoded information regarding popular flavor texts of MtG cards. The numbers listed refer to the number of letters in each word of the text. Punctuation has been preserved. The following acronym represents the name of the card. Using this info, can you name the cards?

- "1 4 1 6 4 3!" **G.T.**
- 9, 2 3 4. **D.C.**
- 4 9 3. **G.O.**
- "5 5 1'1 5 5 4!" **M.O.O.**
- "9 3 2-6!" **I.H.G.T.**
- 3 4 2 3 8. **R.G.**
- "3! 4, 3! 2'1 3 8!" **L.**
- 4 6 5, 3. **P.T.**
- "2 3 8 1 5 5 2 3 5 5." **C.**
- 4 7 4 4 3'1 6. **H.**
- 14...2 12? **B.G.**
- "1 4 4 3 4 2 1 7 2 4." **W.**

Some notes:
- Quotes keep the quotation marks, but I've dropped all attributions included in the flavor text.
- Some cards on the list have multiple printings, some with various differing flavor texts. The flavor text I reference may not necessarily be on all printings of the associated card. You don't have to give the edition if you don't want, but are of course welcome to do so.
- Since this is a multi-part puzzle, to avoid the issue of not knowing who to attribute the accepted answer to in the probable event of split answers, I will make a community answer to keep the focus on reminiscing on sweet/funny/awesome flavor texts.

Comment: Are you sure that last one is correct? I was completely stumped so I brute-forced it and read the flavour text of every printing of every one-word card that starts with W, no matches.

Comment: I'm really disappointed you didn't use "Grow plants in dirt? Save time: eat dirt"

Comment: The last one was a tricky one for sure but it's my favorite flavor text of all time (followed by #2). @orp I've never heard that one! What card is that? Goblin Gardenwrecker?

Comment: @NeedAName: It's Goblin Gardener. Actually I didn't remember it quite right, it's "Grow _food_ in dirt," not plants.

Comment: @orp I though Goblin Gardener jokingly, never would've guessed that was actually the card. Oh, old goblins, bring your hilarity back to magic!

Comment: My favorite: "He exercises his right to bear arms." (Werebear)

Comment: Is this puzzle solved?

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes it is, but because I created the community wiki answer, I cannot accept it until exactly 24 hours after creation (ie in ~4 hours)

Comment: All those flavor texts and no Jaya Ballard? For shame! I demand a sequel!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- "1 4 1 6 4 3!" G.T.

  > "I want a banana this big" ([Gorilla Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=29980))
- 9, 2 3 4. D.C.

  > Greatness, at any cost. ([Dark Confidant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397731))
- 4 9 3. G.O.

  > They certainly are. ([Goblin Offensive](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8818))
- "5 5 1'1 5 5 4!" M.O.O.

  > "Guess where I'm gonna plant this!" ([Might of Oaks, 7th Edition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=13148))
- "9 3 2-6!" I.H.G.T.

  > "Everybody but me - CHARGE!" ([Ib Halfheart, Goblin Tactician](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=157923))
- 3 4 2 3 8. R.G.

  > The root of all greevils. ([Root Greevil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8827))
- "3! 4, 3! 2'1 3 8!" L.

  > Ach! Hans, run! It's the Lhurgoyf!" ([Lhurgoyf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247151))
- 4 6 5, 3. P.T.

  > When nature calls, *run*. ([Primeval Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397688))
- "2 3 8 1 5 5 2 3 5 5." C.

  > "It was probably a lousy spell in the first place." ([Counterspell, Tempest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4693))
- 4 7 4 4 3'1 6. H.

  > When killing five just isn't enough. ([Hex](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247382))
- 14...2 12? B.G.

  > Reinforcements... or refreshments? ([Bottle Gnomes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393819))
- "1 4 4 3 4 2 1 7 2 4." W.

  > It doesn't exist in gatherer but it's a promo (Magic Player Rewards) version of Wasteland:
  >  [image]

Comment: I have no idea what the last one is.

Comment: Added the last one :)

Comment: @IvoBeckers Oh wow, good catch.